# Python: transform equal XML elements into nested children-parent elements

Tags: python, xml, automation, xml.etree

I hope someone can help me solve the following problem.

I have an ugly and large xml file that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <level-0/>
    <level-1/>
    <level-2/>
    <level-3/>
    <level-1/>
    <level-3/>
    <level-2/>
</root>
```

I need to automatically transform it like follows:

```
<root>
    <level-0>
        <level-1>
            <level-2>
                <level-3/>
            </level-2>
        </level-1>
        <level-1>
            <level-3/>
            <level-2/>
        </level-1>
    </level-0>
</root>
```

Note that not always a sub-level has its immediate parent as actual parent. In other words, the nesting rule is: each element has to be nested within the latter element that has a higher level of nesting than itself.

Please consider that I've used xml.etree for a very large piece of code, and keeping it that way would be awesome - still, if it'll be necessary to switch to another package, say lxml, I will.

Any kind of help would be muchly appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT.

this is what I have so far which kind of works:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

level_0 = []
level_1 = []
level_2 = []
level_3 = []

l0 = l1 = l2 = l3 = 0

tree = ET.parse("ugly.xml")
ugly = tree.getroot()

new = ET.Element("root")

for e in ugly:

    if e.tag == "l0":
        new.append(e)
        l0 += 1
        level_0.append(e)
        l1 = l2 = l3 = 0
    elif e.tag == "l1":
        if l1:
            if l0:
                level_0[-1].append(e)
            else:
                new.append(e)
        l1 += 1
        level_1.append(e)
        l2 = l3 = 0
    elif e.tag == "l2":
        if l2:
            if l1:
                level_1[-1].append(e)
            elif l0:
                level_0[-1].append(e)
            else:
                new.append(e)
        l2 += 1
        level_2.append(e)
        l3 = 0
    elif e.tag == "l3":
        level_3.append(e)
        if l2:
            level_2[-1].append(e)
        elif l1:
            level_1[-1].append(e)
        elif l0:
            level_0[-1].append(e)
        else:
            new.append(e)

for level in level_1:
    new.append(level)
else:
    for level in level_2:
        new.append(level)
    else:
        for level in level_3:
            new.append(level)
```

The problem is that sometimes some levels are note appendend.

EDIT 2:

maybe I got it!

```
def appendeep(parent, child):

    def level(elem):
        levels = ["level-0", "level-1", "level-2", "level-3"]
        return levels.index(elem.tag)

    try:
        if level(child) > level(parent[-1]):
            parent[-1] = appendeep(parent[-1], child)
        else:
            parent.append(child)
    except IndexError:
        parent.append(child)

    return parent

tree = ET.Parse("ugly.xml")
ugly = tree.getroot()
new = ET.Element("root")

for e in ugly:
    new = appendeep(new, e)
```

Comment: I've tried a "brutal" solution, which is kind of manual. I nested in a for loop which iterates the original xml elements a series of if-else statements that create separate lists; then I iterate the lists using a for-else loop and append the elements to the (new) root. It works, but it's ugly and rough. I was thinking at some kind of recursive function, but I always end up in an infinte loop.

Comment: Please post your code here , people are more comfortable to discuss on your code and solve your problem